# Prove that orthogonal n x n matrices form a $C^1$ surface of dimension n(n-1)/2 in $\mathbb{R^n}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, matrix-calculus

Consider the function $F:Mat_n → Sym_n$ defined by the formula $F(A) = A∗A$. $Mat_n$ denotes the vector space of n × n matrices with real entries, while $Sym_n$ denotes the vector space of symmetric $n × n$ matrices with real entries. We will also identify $Mat_n$ with $\mathbb{R^n}^2$, and $Sym_n$ with $\mathbb{R^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$

I have a general layout of the proof, but no idea how to actually implement it.
First, I should show that for every $A ∈ Mat_n$, the differential map $DF(A)$ is given by $[DF(A)](B)=A∗B+B∗A$. Next, I should prove that for every invertible matrix $A∈Mat_n$, one has $dim(ker(DF(A)))=\frac{n(n − 1)}{2}$. From all this, I should conclude that the orthogonal $n×n$ matrices form a $C^1$ surface of dimension $\frac{n(n − 1)}{2}$ in $\mathbb{R^n}^2$.

Comment: It looks like all of the ingredients are in place. What are you having difficulty implementing exactly?

Comment: I'm just really struggling with the details. The 'ingredients' are more like a general expected outline that should probably all be true, but I don't know how to formalize it well.

Comment: Perhaps the missing idea is that $O(n)$ is the level set $F^{-1}(I)$. In particular, this means that we can prove the claim by applying the Rank Theorem. In particular, this requires shows that $F$ has constant rank (on the level set).

Comment: I'll try it out, thank you!